# How to run multiple commands via Invoke-Command on remote server

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

In the below example, only the `Get-Process` in my scriptblock is being executed. "deh" does not print for some reason

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName mycomputer -Credential $mycreds -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Process
    Write-Host "deh"
}
```

If I remove `-ComputerName` and execute on local, then it runs both commands just fine.

**EDIT**:

Here I am trying to execute IIS cmdlets against remote server. The following command works

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName mycomputer -ScriptBlock { 
    Trace-Command CommandDiscovery {
        Import-Module webAdministration
        Start-WebAppPool -Name DefaultAppPool
    } -PSHost 
}
```

but this does not work

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName mycomputer -ScriptBlock { 
    Import-Module webAdministration
    Start-WebAppPool -Name DefaultAppPool
}
```

what is special about `Trace-Command` that it is helping Start-WebAppPool to work? this is really odd and I can't explain why this functionality..

Comment: It executes both commands when removing the -ComputerName parameter, so it seems something to do with calling on remote computer

Answer (score 3):

No, the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet takes a *scriptblock*  where you can put *multiple* commands. You should also be able to see the `Write-Host` output.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. It seems to execute both commands when I remove the -ComputerName parameter and execute on local machine. Any idea for what reasons this would be?

Comment: `Write-host` writes to the console, so I think you wouldn't see it because it would occur within the remote session.

Comment: @MarkWragg You will get the output. Thought the same but tested it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `Trace-Command` on the remote machine via `Invoke-Command` to see what is happening. I'm not able to reproduce this.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName mycomputer -Credential $Creds -ScriptBlock { Trace-Command CommandDiscovery {get-process;write-host 'deh'} -PSHost }
```

Comment: something about Trace-Command is allowing my IIS Cmdlets to work against remote servers. But without it, they do not work. Really odd. I have updated OP. any ideas?

Comment: If you are in PS v 3.0 or later, you just try without Importing the WebAdministration module

Answer (score -2):

Try to separate the commands using a semicolon:

```
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName mycomputer -Credential $mycreds -ScriptBlock {
        Get-Process ; 
        Write-Host "deh"
    }
```

Comment: Thats not necessary.

Comment: "deh" does not print. no difference